# What is the scope of a C++ class added to a QList

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I wrote a small piece of code to prove to myself some bad practice was indeed bad practice. However I'm not seeing the result I expected. 
I have a QList storing objects rather than pointers to those objects.
Here is the class:

```
class test{
  public:
  test(int value){val=value; printf("created test %d\n",val);}
  ~test(){ printf("deleting test %d\n", val); val=0;}
  void print(){printf("test %d!\n", val);}
  int val;
};
```

and I have a list of these with test functions as follows:

```
class myclass {
...
QList<test> _test_list;
void do_test_init();
void do_test();
...
};

void myclass::do_test_init()
{
  for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    _test_list.append(test(i+100));
}

void myclass::do_test()
{
  for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    _test_list[i].print();    
}
```

The output I see is:

```
created test 100
deleting test 100
created test 101
deleting test 101
created test 102
deleting test 102
created test 103
deleting test 103
created test 104
deleting test 104
created test 105
deleting test 105
created test 106
deleting test 106
created test 107
deleting test 107
created test 108
deleting test 108
created test 109
deleting test 109
test 100!
test 101!
test 102!
test 103!
test 104!
test 105!
test 106!
test 107!
test 108!
test 109!
```

I'm assuming this is because the append function is taking a copy of the object I passed in. Does this mean that it's safe to use QList this way? My preference is to store pointers rather than objects, is this misguided?

Comment: Why should it be unsafe? You just have to be aware what you are doing. Anything that you append to the list is copied and then the list "owns" that object. If you want to keep ownership of the listed object, then simply put pointers in the list. Just depends on what you want to do...

Comment: Please read about the so-called "Law of Three", which is fundamental to C++!

Comment: What do you mean but "safe"?

Comment: guess I was being dumb. after adding a copy constructor as Ulrich suggested it's plain to see what is happening.

Comment: "I have a QList storing objects rather than pointers to those objects." That's how you would be using a `QList` lot of the time anyway :) What's your problem, exactly? Why do you consider it a bad practice?

Comment: I spent a lot of time writing in C which has ingrained in me a preference for storing pointers.  As I've answered below, I don't have no problem no more. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is that it's perfectly "safe" in the sense that the object is copied when it is appended to the list. Providing a copy constructor shows this clearly. 
The copied objects are deleted when the list is cleared.